# rxDart BehaviorSubject's value is not null on sink.addError

Tags: flutter

I'm new to using rxDart & bloc. I implement a transform to validate input. When I listen to the data on the sink it outputed correctly (null if error & value if no error), but when I print the value of the BehaviorSubject it wont represent null on error and prints the value that should be an error. Here is my code:

```
  final _phoneNumberController = BehaviorSubject<String>();

  Function(String) get setPhoneNumber => _phoneNumberController.sink.add;

  Observable<String> get phoneNumberValue =>
      _phoneNumberController.stream.transform(_validatePhoneNumber);

  final _validatePhoneNumber = StreamTransformer<String, String>.fromHandlers(
      handleData: (phoneNumber, sink) {
    if (phoneNumber.length > 5 && isNumeric(phoneNumber)) {
      sink.add(phoneNumber);
    } else {
      sink.addError(StringConstant.phoneNumberValidationErrorMessage);
    }
  });
  void signUserIn() {
    print(_phoneNumberController.stream.value); // Prints value that should be an error
  }

  SignInBloc() {
    phoneNumberValue.listen((data) => print(data)); // Just Fine
  }
```

Comment: The sole purpose of BehaviourSubject is to hold the previous valid data. You should use StreamController instead of BehaviourSubject.

Comment: Oh I see, I'll keep that in mind then. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're listening to data but you don't listen to sink errors. change your code to:

```
 SignInBloc() {
    phoneNumberValue.listen((data) {
      print(data);
      }, 
    onError: (_){
  print(_.toString());
   });
  }
```